# Address Parsing - Floor #

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have some address data that needs parsing. Most of the addresses info is coming in a way that works for me except for floor data.

For floor data I get coming in different ways, I might get the following formats:

"123 Main Street Floor 2" OR "123 Main Street 2nd Floor"

If I'm using a case...when statement to parse my data, how do I get it to determine when to get the number after or the number before? Ultimately I want "Floor 2" for example 1 and "2nd Floor" for example 2.

This is the sql I am currently using.

```
CASE WHEN (addr LIKE 'floor%' and addr LIKE '%[0-9]%' ) THEN SUBSTRING(addr, CHARINDEX('Floor ', addr), 
LEN(addr))
```

Comment: What about this `123 Main Street first floor`

Comment: I suggest solving this at the user interface.  Otherwise the number or permutations and combinations is too great.

Comment: Yep, parse it on input, or and parse the current data set and store the results in the table.

Comment: I'm not worried about getting every combination, just the examples I listed above. The number of other instances is too little to have to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option using the sum of PatIndex()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (addr varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
 ('123 Main Street Floor 2')
,('123 Main Street 2nd Floor')
,('123 Main Street')

select *
       ,FloorNr = NullIf(ltrim(rtrim(substring(addr,patindex('%Floor [1-9]%',addr)+patindex('% [1-9]% Floor',addr),25))),addr)
From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
addr                        FloorNr
123 Main Street Floor 2     Floor 2
123 Main Street 2nd Floor   2nd Floor
123 Main Street             NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you said you are only interested in the examples above...

```
declare @table table (addresses varchar(4000))

insert into @table
values
('123 Main Street Floor 2'),
('123 Main Street 2nd Floor')

select
    case 
        when right(addresses,5) = 'Floor' then right(addresses,CHARINDEX(' ',reverse(addresses),7)) 
        else substring(addresses,charindex('Floor',addresses,1),99) end
from
    @table
```